# Nokogiri scrape text methods alternative?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri

I'm trying to get Nokogiri to scrape ESPN's site for Jeremy Lin's last game stats, however, the CSS text method is giving me a string without any spaces between the stats.

The string that `scraper.get_last_game_stats.text` is returning is:

```
"Sat 11/16vsDENW 122-111326-11.5450-2.0004-6.66747113116Wed 11/13@ PHIL 117-1234910-19.5269-15.6005-6.833512005834Sat 11/9vsLACL 94-107263-7.4290-0.0000-0.0001701156"
```

I am trying to put spaces between each of the stats however, even when I loop through the main object, putting spaces or dashes between iterations, I can't split the numbers for steals, blocks, points, turnovers and everything else:

```
class PlayerScraper
  attr_accessor :player_data, :name

  def initialize(url)
    @player_data = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))
  end

  def get_last_game_stats
    @last_game_stats = @player_data.css('tr[class^="oddrow team-46"]')
  end
end

jlin_url = "http://espn.go.com/nba/player/_/id/4299/jeremy-lin"

scraper = PlayerScraper.new(jlin_url)
scraper.get_last_game_stats.text
```

Can someone show me a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're walking the rows, but not the contained cells. You need to do both to get the cell's values in a usable form:

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'nokogiri'

URL = 'http://espn.go.com/nba/player/_/id/4299/jeremy-lin'
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(URL))

data = doc.css('tr[class^="oddrow team-46"]').map{ |tr|
  tr.css('td').map(&:text)
}

data
# => [["Sat 11/16",
#      "vsDEN",
#      "W 122-111",
#      "32",
#      "6-11",
#      ".545",
#      "0-2",
#      ".000",
#      "4-6",
#      ".667",
#      "4",
#      "7",
#      "1",
#      "1",
#      "3",
#      "1",
#      "16"],
#     ["Wed 11/13",
#      "@ PHI",
#      "L 117-123",
#      "49",
#      "10-19",
#      ".526",
#      "9-15",
#      ".600",
#      "5-6",
#      ".833",
#      "5",
#      "12",
#      "0",
#      "0",
#      "5",
#      "8",
#      "34"],
#     ["Sat 11/9",
#      "vsLAC",
#      "L 94-107",
#      "26",
#      "3-7",
#      ".429",
#      "0-0",
#      ".000",
#      "0-0",
#      ".000",
#      "1",
#      "7",
#      "0",
#      "1",
#      "1",
#      "5",
#      "6"]]
```

Looking at the data differently, this outputs it as the rows:

```
data.each do |row|
  puts row.join(', ')
end
# >> Sat 11/16, vsDEN, W 122-111, 32, 6-11, .545, 0-2, .000, 4-6, .667, 4, 7, 1, 1, 3, 1, 16
# >> Wed 11/13, @ PHI, L 117-123, 49, 10-19, .526, 9-15, .600, 5-6, .833, 5, 12, 0, 0, 5, 8, 34
# >> Sat 11/9, vsLAC, L 94-107, 26, 3-7, .429, 0-0, .000, 0-0, .000, 1, 7, 0, 1, 1, 5, 6
```

A table is really simple and is something you can create using two nested loops. To later access each cell you need to do the same, walk the rows in a loop, and, inside that loop, walk the cells. That's all the code I wrote does.

See "[How to avoid joining all text from Nodes when scraping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43594656/how-to-avoid-joining-all-text-from-nodes-when-scraping)" also.

Comment: Thank you so much! amazing answer. Just what i was looking for

Answer (score 1):

I think you should read the `tr` elements and then cycle its HTML content and handle each single `td` separately, otherwise using the `text` method and the Rails HTML tags cleanup you are getting a mess from the original data.

Answer (score 1):

the `text` method concats the text of all the the selected nodes. Try something like

```
scraper.get_last_game_stats.map(&:text)
```

If you want the `tr` nodes to be evaluated separately. When I do that w/ the url you point to I get:

```
["Sat 11/16", "vsDEN", "W 122-111", "32", "6-11", ".545", "0-2", ".000", "4-6", ".667", "4", "7", "1", "1", "3", "1", "16", "Wed 11/13", "@ PHI", "L 117-123", "49", "10-19", ".526", "9-15", ".600", "5-6", ".833", "5", "12", "0", "0", "5", "8", "34", "Sat 11/9", "vsLAC", "L 94-107", "26", "3-7", ".429", "0-0", ".000", "0-0", ".000", "1", "7", "0", "1", "1", "5", "6"]
```

which I hope looks more like what you are looking for.